# Evaluate listed strings to create function object in r

Tags: r, function, evaluate

I need a function created by a list of commands to fully evaluate so that it is identical to the "manual" version of the function.

Background: I am  using ScaleR functions in Microsoft R Server and need to apply a set of transformations as a function. ScaleR is very picky about needing to be passed a function that is phrased **exactly** as specified below:

```
functionThatWorks <- function(data) { 
  data$marital_status_p1_ismarried <- impute(data$marital_status_p1_ismarried)
  return(data)
}
```

I have a function that creates this list of transformations (and hundreds more, hence the need to functionalize its writing).

```
transformList <- list ("data$ismarried <- impute(data$ismarried)",
                 "data$issingle <- impute(data$issingle)")
```

This line outputs the evaluated string that I want to the console, but I am unaware of a way to move it from console output to being used in a function:

```
cat(noquote(unlist(bquote(  .(noquote(transformList[1]))))))
```

I need to evaluate *functionIWant* so that it is identical to *functionThatWorks*.

```
functionIWant <- function(data){
  eval(  cat(noquote(unlist(bquote(  .(noquote(transformList[1])))))) )
  return(data)
}

identical(functionThatWorks, functionIWant)
```

EDIT: Adding in the answer based on @dww 's code. It works well in ScaleR. It is identical, minus meaningless spacing.

```
functionIWant <- function(){}
formals(functionIWant) <- alist(data=NULL)
functionIWant.text <- parse(text = c(
  paste( bquote(  .(noquote(transformList[1]))), ";", "return(data)\n")
))
body(functionIWant) <- as.call(c(as.name("{"), functionIWant.text))
```

Comment: maybe try something with eval(parse(text=...)) or eval(substitute(...))

Comment: Thanks, but I have done a lot of dancing around this code using eval(), parse(), bquote(), unlist(), and noquote() and have not had success. No attempted combination creates a function object that is identical to the "manual" entry. The function object contains only the code entered, not what that code should evaluate into.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this?

```
# 1st define a 'hard-coded' function    
f1 <- function (x = 2) 
{
    y <- x + 1
    y^2
}

f1(3)
# [1] 16

# now create  a similar function from a character vector  
f2 <- function(){}
formals(f2) <- alist(x=2)
f2.text <- parse(text = c('y <- x + 1', 'y^2'))
body(f2) <- as.call(c(as.name("{"), f2.text))

f2(3)
# [1] 16
```